# Indeterminate form $0^0$ using L'hospitals rule when calculating $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given the question $$\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{\sin(x)}$$

I have deducted so far that this has the indeterminate form $0^0$ so I have taken the natural logarithm of both sides to give me: $$\lim_{x\to0^+} \ln(y) = \lim_{x\to0^+}\sin(x)\ln(x)$$
This still has an indeterminate form so I rearrange it to start using L'hospitals rule: $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{\csc(x)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac1x}{-\csc(x)\cot(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\sin(x)\tan(x)}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\cos(x)\sec^2(x)}{1} = -1$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{\sin(x)} = \frac1e$$

I don't think this is correct, am I doing something wrong, and if so, where?

Comment: You miscomputed the derivative of $\sin (x)\tan(x)$. We have $(f\cdot g)' = f'\cdot g + f\cdot g'$, not $f'\cdot g'$.

Comment: oh wow! what a silly mistake. I shall fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{\sin(x)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0^+} \exp(\ln(x)\sin(x))$$

$$=\exp(\lim_{x\to0^+} \ln(x)\sin(x))$$

$$=\exp(\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/\sin(x)})$$

Applying L'Hôpital's rule:

$$=\exp(\lim_{x\to0^+} -\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x\cos(x)})$$

$$=\exp(-1\cdot \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x})$$

$$=\exp(-\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x})$$

Applying L'Hôpital's rule:

$$=\exp(-\lim_{x\to0^+} 2\cos(x)\sin(x))$$

$$\color{grey}{e^0=1}$$

$$=\boxed {\color{blue}1}$$

Comment: Is my answer below also correct mehtod?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with equivalents:
$$\sin x\ln x\sim_0 x\ln x \xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{} 0\qquad\text{(basic result)}$$
hence $\;x^{\sin x}=\mathrm e^{\sin x\ln x} \to 1 $.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \ln(y) = \lim_{x\to0^+}\sin(x)\ln(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{\csc(x)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac1x}{-\csc(x)\cot(x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\sin(x)\tan(x)}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-\cos(x)\tan(x)-\sin(x)\sec^2(x)}{1} = \frac01 = 0$$
Therefore $$=\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{\sin(x)} = e^0 = 1$$